# Existence of a almost increase $\omega_1^{\omega_1}$ sequence mod $[\omega_1]^{<\omega_1}$ with length $\omega_2$

Tags: set-theory, ordinal-numbers

In my textbook, the author said that the sequence below is satisfied the requirement.
$$\text{For }\alpha<\omega_1,\forall\gamma<\omega_1,g_\alpha(\gamma)=\alpha, \text{For }\omega_1\le\alpha<\omega_2,\text{Let }h_\alpha\colon\omega_1\rightarrow\alpha\text{ is a bijection},\forall\gamma<\omega_1,g_\alpha(\gamma)=\operatorname{ot}(h_\alpha[\gamma])$$
ot means the ordinal type of a ordinal number set under $\in$ order.

I want to ask why when $\alpha\ge\omega_1,\beta<\alpha$, there is $g_\alpha$ almost larger than $g_\beta$ mod ideal $[\omega_1]^{<\omega_1}$.

Comment: This needn't work. E.g. let $h_{\omega_1+1}:\omega_1\to\omega_1+1$ be the bijection $h$ with $h(0)=\omega_1$ and $h(n+1)=n$ for $n<\omega$ and $h(\beta)=\beta$ for $\beta\in[\omega,\omega_1)$, and let $h_{\omega_1}:\omega_1\to\omega_1$ be a bijection $h$ such that for all ordinals $\eta$ which are a limit of limit ordinals, we have $h[\eta]=\eta$ and $h[\eta+n\cdot\omega]=\eta+(n+1)\cdot\omega$ for all $n\in[1,\omega)$...

Comment: Define $g_{\omega_1}$ and $g_{\omega_1+1}$ from these as you did. Then for all $\eta<\omega_1$ which are a limit of limit ordinals, we have $g_{\omega_1}(\eta+\omega)=\eta+\omega+\omega>\eta+\omega+1=g_{\omega_1+1}(\eta+\omega)$.

Comment: What's the book?